# ProgressHUD problems with Asynchronous request

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, asynchronous

I'm trying to progressHUD in the Asynchronous request, but it does not seem to work probably. What i want is it to show the progessHUD until the Asynchronous request is done. at the moment it is not showing in the beginning, but after 3 sec it is showing for 0.1 second or something and after that the Asynchronous request is completed. What am i doing wrong, to achieve that the progessHUD is shown when the viewisloaded to the Asynchronous request is done?

As you can see below i've added progressHUD show and dismiss in the viewDidLoad and in the firstRequest method.

Viewdidload:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[ProgressHUD show:@"Please Wait..."];
buttonLogin = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionLogin)];
buttonLogout = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionLogout)];

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
self.theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight-160) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.theTableView.dataSource = self;
self.theTableView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.theTableView];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};

fixtures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



[self firstRequest];

self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-100, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

self.theTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0f green:243/255.0f blue:247/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0f green:243/255.0f blue:247/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

[self checkAuthStatus];

[ProgressHUD dismiss];


}
```

the request:

```
-(void)firstRequest
{



NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {

     [ProgressHUD show:@"Please Wait..."];

         jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];



         int subObjects = ((NSArray *)jsonResult[@"match"]).count;
         for (int i = 0; i <= subObjects-1; i++) {

             NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"playdate"] objectAtIndex:i], [[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"time"] objectAtIndex:i]];
             NSString *identifier = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];

             NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
             [df setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Arizona"]];
             [df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:identifier]];
             [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

             NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date]];





             NSArray *items = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myDate] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];


             NSString *home = [[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"hometeam"] objectAtIndex:i];
             NSString *away = [[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"awayteam"] objectAtIndex:i];
             NSString *league = [[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"league"] objectAtIndex:i];




             [fixtures addObject:
              [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
               items[0], @"date",
               items[1], @"time",
               home, @"home",
               away, @"away",
               league, @"league",
               nil]];

             [sections addObject:
              [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
               items[0], @"date",
               nil]];


         }



     NSArray *copy = [sections copy];
     NSInteger index = [copy count] - 1;
     for (id object in [copy reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
         if ([sections indexOfObject: object inRange: NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) {
             [sections removeObjectAtIndex: index];
         }

         index--;
     }



     NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
     NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
     NSArray* reverseTheArray = [[sections valueForKey:@"date"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
     reversedArray = [[reverseTheArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

     [self.theTableView reloadData];


     [ProgressHUD dismiss];
     }




 ];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show `ProgressHUD` before sending a request.

Your code should look like this.

```
-(void)firstRequest
{
   [ProgressHUD show:@"Please Wait..."];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
         NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
       // request processing stuff
       ...
       [ProgressHUD dismiss];
     }
];
```

---

**Explanation**. When you call `sendAsynchronousRequest...` the request itself performed somewhere in background thread. The network operation may take some time, 1-5-10 seconds. Your `completionHandler` will be executed once the request completes (*after* the delay). So you should show `ProgressHUD` *before* sending a request. Then start the request. And dismiss `ProgressHUD` *at the end* of your `completionHandler` block after everything is processed.

---

**Update** 
There is one more issue I noticed in your code. `viewDidLoad` method is called only *once* on view controller when its view is loaded but at this point the view itself is not presented on screen. So you will not actually see `ProgressHUD` called from `viewDidLoad`. You may be interested in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods if you want to handle when view is presented on screen.

---

I assume your view controller is designed to show data retrieved from web api. I believe the best option is to call your api in `viewWillAppear`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    buttonLogin = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionLogin)];
    buttonLogout = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionLogout)];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    self.theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight-160) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.theTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.theTableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.theTableView];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};

    fixtures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-100, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

    self.theTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0f green:243/255.0f blue:247/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0f green:243/255.0f blue:247/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    [self checkAuthStatus];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated


{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self firstRequest];
}

-(void)firstRequest
{
    [ProgressHUD show:@"Please Wait..."];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         // request processing stuff
         ...
         [ProgressHUD dismiss];
     }
     ];
}
```